# Need a C# function to get SDCard serial in .NET CF

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework

I've seen it written in C++ which I don't know. I need a C# function that return SDCard's serial in .NET CF. Could anyone kindly help me write a function with it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compact Framework - Get Storage Card Serial Number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/552681/compact-framework-get-storage-card-serial-number)

Comment: Yes, I know sdf. But due to security concern, I would like a function in my own exe file. So that I can obfuscate.

Comment: How is it a security concern?  The APIs to get the serial number are public and the serial number is not hidden.

Comment: I just want to obfuscate entire assembly so the function is hidden somewhere inside thousands of functions in a single class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I'll say that if you buy the SDF ($50) you get the source for this function, which you could then pull into your project and obfuscate.

If, however, you have more time than money and want to implement it yourself, I can point you in the right direction.  I leave it to you to string all of these pieces together, but here are the steps:

First, you have to open the Volume like this:

```
IntPtr hFile = NativeMethods.CreateFile(
      string.Format("{0}\\Vol:", driveName), 
      NativeMethods.GENERIC_READ, 0, 0, NativeMethods.OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
```

That gives you a handle to the drive.  You then simply call an IOCTL to get the storage ID:

```
byte[] data = new byte[512];
int returned;
int result = NativeMethods.DeviceIoControl(
             hFile, IOCTL_DISK_GET_STORAGEID, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 
             data, data.Length, out returned, IntPtr.Zero);
if (result != 0)
{
    m_storageID = STORAGE_IDENTIFICATION.FromBytes(data);
}
```

What this gives you is a binary representation of a [STORAGE_IDENTIFICATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa448149.aspx) structure.  Note that the structure is really only a desciption of the header of the data.  It contains an offset to the actual serial number data, which is an ASCII string.  Extracting it looks something like this:

```
int snoffset = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 12);

string sn = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, snoffset, data.Length - snoffset);
return sn.TrimEnd(new char[] { '\0' });
```

Comment: Using SDF Community edition for testing, I'm getting null in both ManufacturerID and SerialNumber. How could I solve it? I'm on WinCE 6.

Comment: Check the flags in the STORAGE_IDENTIFICATION to see if it thinks teh values are valid.  It's possible that your SD driver simply doesn't support retrieving these.

Comment: According to https://jo0ls-dotnet-stuff.blogspot.com/2008/12/read-sd-card-cid-serial-number.html, using `IOCTL_DISK_GET_STORAGEID` will just "return a number assigned when the volume is created. It will change next time the drive is formatted." That can't be the serial number of the chip. Is jo0ls wrong, or this answer?

Answer (score 1):

The smart device framework will enable you to do this:

```
foreach(var info in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
{
   string manufacturer = info.ManufacturerID ?? "[Not available]");
   string serial = info.SerialNumber ?? "[Not available]");
}
```

See [here](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2009/03/31/GettingAnSDCardSerialNumberInTheCompactFramework.aspx). I asked the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552681/compact-framework-get-storage-card-serial-number) myself last year.

Comment: Yes, I know sdf. But due to security concern, I would like a function in my own exe file. So that I can obfuscate.

Comment: Good luck. Be sure to post back here if you get an alternative.